# new Date().getTime() gets milliseconds since page is loaded when passed as argument into a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a javascript animation with `window.requestAnimationFrame`. It should be triggered when a button is clicked (like the "dropping" animation of a dropdown menu appearing). I use the variable `timeElapsed` to calculate the time since the button is clicked, and calculate the new height of the object with timeElapsed. I pass the time when the button is clicked (`start`) as an argument of the function. According to my console, although `start` (computed outside the function) is computed correctly, for some reason it **changes to the time since the page is loaded once it is passed into the function**.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function mobileAppear(sTime) {
    console.log(sTime); //Prints milliseconds since page is loaded
    currTime = new Date().getTime();
    timeElapsed = (currTime - sTime)/1000;
    newHeight = timeElapsed*10 ;
    wishlist.style.height = newHeight + "vh";
    if (newHeight < 66){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(mobileAppear);
    }
}

function toggleView() {
  //Some code here
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  console.log(start); // works fine
  if (window.innerWidth < 768){
    mobileAppear(start);
  }
  
}
```

What's the problem here and how to fix that?

*Note: there's probably another mistake in the chunk of code, but for now I'm trying to fix this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of your code is that `requestAnimationFrame` will pass a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) to the callback function, in this case, `mobileAppear`. So `sTime` will not be the same as you get at `toggleView`.

You can move the `start` and `sTime` out like this:

```js
let sTime = 0;

function mobileAppear() {
    console.log(sTime); //Prints milliseconds since page is loaded
    currTime = new Date().getTime();
    timeElapsed = (currTime - sTime)/1000;
    newHeight = timeElapsed*10 ;
    wishlist.style.height = newHeight + "vh";
    if (newHeight < 66){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(mobileAppear);
    }
}

function toggleView() {
    //Some code here
    sTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(sTime); // works fine
    if (window.innerWidth < 768){
        mobileAppear();
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, `DOMHighResTimeStamp` can be treated as `elapsedTime`. So a better way  to solve your problem might be:

```js
function mobileAppear(timeElapsed=0) {
    // console.log(sTime);
    // currTime = new Date().getTime();
    // timeElapsed = (currTime - sTime)/1000;
    newHeight = timeElapsed*10 ;
    wishlist.style.height = newHeight + "vh";
    if (newHeight < 66){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(mobileAppear);
    }
}

function toggleView() {
    //Some code here
    // sTime = new Date().getTime();
    // console.log(sTime); // works fine
    if (window.innerWidth < 768){
        window.requestAnimationFrame( mobileAppear );
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It works! The first method is exactly what I need because it calculates the height since the button is clicked; the second method is calculating the height based on the milliseconds since the time origin (which makes sense because it is based on DOMHighResTimeStamp - at least that's what I get the MDN doc).

Answer (score 1):

You want to let `window.requestAnimationFrame` handle your timestamps for you see below:

[Here is the part of the MDN docs that I've had to follow in the past](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#example)

```js
const wishlist = document.getElementById('wishlist')
const button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener('click', toggleView)

let startTime

function mobileAppear(curTime) {
    if (startTime === undefined) startTime = curTime
    const timeElapsed = (curTime - startTime)/1000;
    const newHeight = timeElapsed * 10;
    wishlist.style.height = newHeight + "px"; // I changed this to pixels for the example
    if (newHeight < 66){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(mobileAppear);
    }
}

function toggleView() {
  //Some code here
  // let requestAnimationFrame handle sending the current timestamp
  window.requestAnimationFrame(mobileAppear)
}

button.addEventListener('click', toggleView)
```

```html
<div id="wishlist" style="width: 200px; height: 1px; margin: 10px; background: red"></div>
<button id="button">Toggle View</button>
```